# Compilation issues with gcc 4.3 version in linux

Tags: c++

Recently we are upgraded from gcc 4.1.2 to 4.3. My project was compiled with gcc 4.1.2 without any errors. But getting compilation issues 4.3 without any changes.

This is the error: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âFILEâ with no type

It can be resolved if I include header file. But in gcc 4.1.2 I dont see this error. I am getting only in gcc 4.3. I would lie to know is their any way to solve without adding header file.

Comment: Not including the header files that declares something is wrong, even it it happens to work. If you need to use structures, types and functions from the`<cstdio>` header file you should explicitly  include it.

Comment: As for *why* it worked before, it's probably because some other system header file included the one you needed. This is a non-portable implementation detail that should not be counted on, as you now know.

Comment: Yikes, you are still using a very old version of GCC after upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It can be resolved if I include header file.

Good.  That's the way you're *supposed* to make use of library functions and methods.

> I would lie to know is their any way to solve without adding header
>   file.

No, there is not.

You're lucky your code previously compiled and worked without the proper header files.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have one doubt, any default search path for gcc compiler it look for builtin function definitions(standard function provided  by C compiler)?